# Best way to display multiple searches from Google simultaneously on one page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of search terms. Each one is being sent as a parameter to a search - like Google, the response captured to an array of responses, with the key to the array, the original search term.

I now want to render each one onto a page in a grid of responses. What is the best way to display each response? Should I put each set of HTML into a div on the page, or should I put it into an iframe?  Are iframes still acceptable things to use? I know frames are frowned upon, are iframes in the same category?

Answer (score 2):

You would only want them in an IFRAME if you wanted the user to be able to navigate within each set of results separately. Otherwise, use separate DIVs.